# Why an undefined functions is actually called from Javascript clousure?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am studying this piece of code

```
var myModule = function () {


    //"private" variables:
    var myPrivateVar = "01I can be accessed only from within YAHOO.myProject.myModule.";

    //"private" method:
    var myPrivateMethod = function () {
        console.log("02I can be accessed only from within YAHOO.myProject.myModule");
    }


    return  {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty.",
        myPublicMethod: function () {
            console.log("1I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod.");

            //Within myProject, I can access "private" vars and methods:
            console.log("2"+myPrivateVar);
            console.log("3"+myPrivateMethod());

            //The native scope of myPublicMethod is myProject; we can
            //access public members using "this":
            console.log("4"+this.myPublicProperty);
        }
    };

}();
```

and wondering about the output:

```
1I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod.
201I can be accessed only from within YAHOO.myProject.myModule.
02I can be accessed only from within YAHOO.myProject.myModule
3undefined
4I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty.
```

can anyone explain why     **02I can be accessed only from within YAHOO.myProject.myModule** is output if the `myPrivateMethod()` is undefined as shown in the output? and why it is displayed before `console.log("3"+myPrivateMethod())` ?

Comment: The function call `myPrivateMethod()` **returns** `undefined`. Logging is a side effect of the call.

Answer (score 2):

> can anyone explain why 02I can be accessed only from within YAHOO.myProject.myModule is output if the myPrivateMethod() is undefined as shown in the output?

`myPrivateMethod` is not `undefined`. `myPrivateMethod()` is. The function is defined, it has no `return` statement so its return value is `undefined`.

> and why it is displayed before console.log("3"+myPrivateMethod()) ?

`myPrivateMethod()` is evaluated (so the function is executed and the `console.log` statement inside it is fired) before it can be concatenated with the string `"3"` and passed to the other `console.log`.